# How to solve depending probability questions using tree diagrams when exchanging takes place

Tags: probability

In Sirimal's cattle pound, there are 5 bulls and 15 cows. In Nadan's cattle pound there are 2 bulls and 8 cows. Sirimal and Nadan agree to exchange one animal each. After Sirimal randomly selects one animal and sends it to Nadan, Nadan randomly selects one animal and sends it to Sirimal. 
 How do i draw the relevant sample spave in a tree diagram ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? Do you have a tree diagram that you think *might* be right that we can comment on?

Comment: What difficulty are you having with this?  For each outcome at a particular decision (*or group of outcomes which are all similar*) you branch out in a direction corresponding to that outcome as having been what was selected for that decision.  For your first point where it splits onto different branches... set the one branch for if Sirimal sent a bull versus if Sirimal sent a cow...  Now, there is another branching point ahead for each corresponding to which Nadan sent.  All that remains is labeling your diagram with appropriate numbers to organize your thoughts for later calculation.

Comment: What do you think is the probability when there is a reduction in tje number of bulls in Sirimal's pound because of the exchange?

Comment: i named the first branch as sirimal sending a bull versus sirimal sending a cow. In which i mentioned the probabilities as 5/20 and 15/20. Then i drew branches (from those 2 branches i drew for Sirimal's pound) and named as Nadan's pound. And there i named as sending a bull versus sending a cow. And i mentioned the probabilities as 2/10 and 8/10.

Comment: Is this right? I mean my tree diagram

Comment: If Sirimal sent a bull, then Nadan has 3 bulls and 8 cows. If Sirimal sent a cow, then Nadan has 2 bulls and 9 cows. So, depending on the prior choice, it will change the probabilities for which animal Nadan will send back.

Comment: Yeah that will change. Then the total number in the second branches also will change is that so?

Comment: Will you be able to upload a picture of the tree diagram ? I cant upload at the moment because i'm new to this. If not i could show my workings

Comment: Im damn stuck in this. Can someone help me with a rough diagram of the tree diagram?